# filter table WHERE 1 column = column from another table

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'll try to explain this the best I can.

I have a drop down populated with country names from one table. When someone selects say Canada, I need a second dropdown to filter the results from a second table called regions.

Here is the code I'm using

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM location_region";

$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo "<select id='province_select' name='province_select' class='province_select' style='width:540px' value=''></option>";

while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value=$nt[value]>$nt[name]</option>"

}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

I know I have to change the Query, but can I do something like:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM location_region WHERE country EQUALS value FROM location_country";
```

This doesn't work, but is there another where of writing this? The table 
"location_region" has a column named "country" that should be equal to the column "value" from the table "location_country"

Thanks as always

EDIT: For Gershon Herczeg here is the table structure

location_country is something similar to:

```
ID name          value
1  Canada        CA 
2  Great Britain GB
3  United States US
```

location_region is similar to:

```
ID name             value  country
1  Alberta          AB     CA
2  Alabama          AL     US
3  British Columbia BC     CA
```

Comment: Are you posting the page to the server when the first `select` changes?  Or are you making an AJAX call when it changes to dynamically populate the second `select`?  How you organize your code changes depending on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is called an inner join - it'll effectively give you one big collection of rows matched on a column or columns specified.

```
SELECT lr.* 
FROM location_region lr
INNER JOIN location_country lc on lr.country = lc.country
WHERE lr.country = <selected value from dropdown>
```

Replacing in the selected value into the query, this should give you everything from the regions table for the country you've selected.

However, if you have a country column in the regions table which matches values in your dropdown, why don't you just select from that to begin with?

```
SELECT * 
FROM location_region 
WHERE country = <selected value from dropdown>
```

Comment: Thanks Bridge, I haven't dealt with JOINS yet, this makes sense though, I'm gonna find a tutorial, Id rather know it then just get the code, thanks.

Comment: Hence why I tried to explain it a little - there are different types of joins as well, for when you want all rows from one or both table(s) even if there is no match in the corresponding ones - all depends on your needs.

Comment: Hey thanks alot, went through some tutorials got it working... somewhat...However this opens a lot of avenues to experiment thank for taking the time to explain this to me.

Comment: No problem - we all started somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

The query can be written like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM location_region, location_country WHERE location_region.country = location_country.value WHERE location_region.country = {USER INPUT}"
```

Comment: Thanks this almost works, however it still shows all regions, since I have regions for several countries is there a way to limit it just to those results?

Comment: Yes, You can add another where clause to search on the country. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well to get a full answer you need to post the fields in your two tables, but it should something of this sort:

```
SELECT location_region.name FROM location_region LEFT JOIN location_country ON location_regions.country = location_country.value
```